# how to separate one array into two, base on its id using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im strugling with this array:

first id = 1

items for the second id = 12,21,34,33;

second id = 2

items for the second id = 21,12,34

It looks like this in my array :

arr = [12 1,21 1,34 1,33 1,21 2,12 2,34 2]

i want to store it like this:

id | item_id

1       12

1       21

1    34

1  33

2  21

2 12

2 34

here's my code :

var item_id = new Array();

$("td.items").each(function() {

if(this){

item_id.push($(this).attr('id'));

}

});

Comment: please tidy up your question!

Comment: You list php and javascript as tags here. Which language do you want? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i use jquery for that

Answer (score 0):

There is a good javascript library for tables manipulations named underscore.js. You can find this here: [underscore js library](http://underscorejs.org/)

jQuery is not designed for tables manipulations but for easy JS DOM operations. Make a deeper research on mensioned above underscore library. There is everything what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in console

```
var arr = ["12 1","21 1","34 1","33 1","21 2","12 2","34 2"]
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = []
$.each(arr,function(k,v){
  var id = v.split(" ")[1]
  var value = v.split(" ")[0]
  if (id == 1){
    arr1.push(value)
  }else if(id == 2){
    arr2.push(value)
  }
});
```

Result

```
arr1
["12", "21", "34", "33"]

arr2
["21", "12", "34"]
```

Do you need like this?